# Equivalence principle(s) and geodesic equation(s)

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics, equivalence-principle, modified-gravity

The equivalence principle (EP) is often stated in many different forms, sometimes leading to different interpretations. To make things easier for beginners to understand, I find it useful to give a quantitative example of a theory or equation that satisfies/violates some version of the EP.

Here are the working definitions of weak, Einstein, and strong equivalence principle that I wish to adhere to, which I realise could be made more precise (but hopefully they're understandable as is):

1. ***Weak EP***: At every spacetime point, in a small enough region, it is possible to choose a local inertial frame (LIF) such that the *laws of motion* for a freely falling test particle take the same form as in Special Relativity.
2. ***Einstein EP***: At every spacetime point, in a small enough region, it is possible to choose a LIF such that the *non-gravitational laws of physics* for a freely falling test particle take the same form as in Special Relativity.
3. ***Strong EP***: At every spacetime point, in a small enough region, it is possible to choose a LIF such that the *laws of physics* for a freely falling *self-gravitating* particle take the same form as in Special Relativity.

The substantial difference between WEP & EEP, as stated above, is that the EEP extends the discussion to all (non-gravitational) laws of physics. For the SEP, we now assume things to hold for self-gravitating bodies also.

The WEP implies that (test) particles move along geodesics. A test particle of mass $m$ in GR can be described by the action
$$
S_1 = -m \int \sqrt{-g_{\mu \nu} \dot{x}^{\mu}  \dot{x}^{\nu}} d \tau \, ,
$$
which upon extremizing leads to the geodesic equation $\nabla_{v}v^{\mu}=0$, where $v^{\mu} := \dot{x}^{\mu} = dx^{\mu}/d\tau$. This therefore satisfies the WEP.

Considering an alternative action, in some non-GR theory, described by
$$
S_2 = -m \int e^{\phi} \sqrt{-g_{\mu \nu} \dot{x}^{\mu}  \dot{x}^{\nu}} d \tau \, ,
$$
where $\phi = \phi(x(\tau))$ is some scalar field. E.g., scalar-tensor theory in the Einstein frame. The resulting equation of motion is not the standard geodesic equation, therefore $\nabla_{v}v^{\mu} \neq 0$, and the theory violates the WEP. If there are any errors, or not-so-clear parts, of the explanation above, please do point this out.

Moving on to my question, are there any similar arguments that can be extended for differentiating between the WEP, EEP and SEP? I'm aware of certain theories that violate the SEP$^1$, but none that present a simple quantitative explanation of how/why this is the case. I also know that calculations of self-force in GR can become very complicated, so perhaps there is not a simple answer. Ideally, I'd write down an action for a (self-gravitating) massive particle that satisfies the geodesic equation in the limit that the self-interaction goes to zero $m_{self} \rightarrow 0$, but violates the SEP otherweise.

Any further references would be useful. In particular, references to objects with internal structure (e.g., intrinsic spin) that violate some version of the EP would be useful! Similar questions have been asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252905/an-example-of-a-theory-that-respects-the-weak-equivalence-principle-but-violates) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535584/why-is-einstein-equivalence-principle-the-basic-assumption-for-gerneral-relativi), but with somewhat unsatisfactory answers, and not with reference to geodesic equations.

*$^1$I've also read that *all* non-GR theories violate the SEP, which is claimed in https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.4438. They also state that higher-derivative gravity violates the SEP, in contradiction to https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7377 .* However, these arguments are very qualitative.

Comment: It is not my expert field but that two references are possible related to your question: [Equivalence Principle in Classical and Quantum Gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.00133v1) and  [Quasi-geodesics in relativistic gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.05891). The second deals with the 'not standard' geodesic equation you mentioned. By the way, Einstein EP postulates the equality of gravitational and inertial mass. For me it means that the mass does not play any role in GR.

Comment: Try [Einstein's Happiest Moment: The Equivalence Principle](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.13781) by Paul Worden and James Overduin (2022). From page 9 it could be interesting for you.